# display json datas table view in segmented control

Tags: ios, iphone, json, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

[image: i need to display in table view as in image]

friends,
i need to display list of details as in image in a table view datas from json service I tried the below code but it doesnot work out

```
(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"unrealized";

    samplecell *cell = (samplecell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"unrealized" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

else if(mySegmentedcontrol.selectedSegmentIndex==3)
{
    settings.hidden=YES;
    connection.hidden=YES;
    openTrades.hidden=YES;
    closedTrades.hidden=NO;
    NSString *link=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.dummydata.com/MMWS/Client/ClosedTrades.ashx?ClientId=%@",clientId];
    NSURL *URLGet=[NSURL URLWithString:link];
    NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URLGet];
    NSError *error;
    jsonReturnArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
    NSLog(@"json%@",jsonReturnArray);
    cell.unRealizedProfit.text=[[jsonReturnArray valueForKey:@"Profit"]objectAtIndex:0];
    cell.strategy.text=[[jsonReturnArray valueForKey:@"StrategyName"]objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *totalProfit=[[jsonReturnArray valueForKey:@"TotalProfit"]objectAtIndex:0];
    closedTotalUnrealizedProfit.text=totalProfit;
}



    NSString *cellValue = [jsonReturnArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.unRealizedProfit.text=cellValue;
    cell.unRealizedProfit.text = [jsonReturnArray valueForKey:@"Profit"];
    cell.strategy.text =[jsonReturnArray valueForKey:@"StrategyName"];

    return cell;

}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"json%@",jsonReturnArray);
    return jsonReturnArray.count;

}
```

I also tried the code and donot know how to bring tableview property in seegmented control

```
else if(mySegmentedcontrol.selectedSegmentIndex==3)
     {
         settings.hidden=YES;
         connection.hidden=YES;
         openTrades.hidden=YES;
         closedTrades.hidden=NO;
         strategyClosed.hidden=NO;
         NSString *link=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.dummmydata.com/MMWS/Client/ClosedTrades.ashx?ClientId=%@",clientId];
         NSURL *URLGet=[NSURL URLWithString:link];
         NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URLGet];
         NSError *error;
         jsonReturnArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
         NSLog(@"json%@",jsonReturnArray);

     }
```

Comment: What doesn't work exactly ? You shouldn't use "else if" as you use it after an "if (cell == nil)", because it's says: "If cell doesn't exists, we create it", if cell exists, we fill it with info". But in the case of cell wasn't there, then you never filled it.

Comment: i need to display those datas in table view and datas are from json service I am new in this coding i tried to display those datas in labels but it worked. I dont know how to display in table view please refer me some code

Comment: i dont know how to bring table view properties inside segment control ie, i dont know how to use segment control to displaya partcular view and get datas  as  table view please guide me

Comment: Then I'd suggest to learn first how `UISegmentedControl` works, how `UITableView` works and then combine.

Comment: i know how a table view works and customizing. Problem is dont know how to bring table view in segment control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### finally i got the answer i customized the cell and used below code for assigning number of rows depending on counts of array

```
(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return jsonReturnArray.count;
}
```

then i displayed in table view using below code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"samplecell";

    samplecell *cell = (samplecell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    //loads two table view for  open and closed trades with reference of client id
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        //table view for closed trades
        if (tableView==strategyClosed) 
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"samplecell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *link=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.managedtradingsystems.com/MMWS/Client/ClosedTrades.ashx?ClientId=%@",clientId];
            NSURL *URLGet=[NSURL URLWithString:link];
            NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URLGet];
            NSError *error;
            jsonReturnArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
            //checks whether datas are present in array or array and datas present are null and displays datas present through labels
             if (![jsonReturnArray isEqual:[NSNull null]])
             {
            NSString *strategy=[[jsonReturnArray valueForKey:@"StrategyName"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            if (![strategy isEqual:[NSNull null]]) 
            {

            cell.strategy.text=strategy;
            }
            else
            {
                cell.strategy.text=@"";
            }
```

the number of rows by below code using array count

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return jsonReturnArray.count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK,

Your data source should not be get within the function cellForRowAtIndexPath,   CellForRowAtIndexPath is for showing each cell of the row based on the tableView's dataSource. And apparently you should not get the datasource when each of the cell is rendering.

You should always make sure your tableView's dataSource is ready before you call [myTableView reloadData];

Solutions: in your viewDidAppear function block, write your logic as below

```
if(mySegmentedcontrol.selectedSegmentIndex==3){
    NSString *link=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.dummydata.com/MMWS/Client/ClosedTrades.ashx?ClientId=%@",clientId];
    NSURL *URLGet=[NSURL URLWithString:link];
    NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URLGet];
    NSError *error;
    self.jsonDataSource = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

    [self.thisTableView reloadData];
}
```

And then in your CellForRowAtIndexPath, do the normal thing like below

```
NSDictionary *objCellData = [self.jsonDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.cellData = objCellData;
return cell;
```

And then , in your Cell class, make sure you draw the title label, or value lable correctly by using the cellData it is assigned.

Please read the UITableView documentation before you code.

The UITableView rendering sequence is

1. DataSource is ready
2. Call [tableView reloadData];
3. UITableView dataSource/delegate functions will be fired, like numberOfRowsInSection, heightForRowAtIndexPath, cellForRowAtIndexPath, etc.

Comment: cell.cellData = objCellData;
return cell;
how can i display the values in label that i assigned in cell please explain in detail. How to take the values from array(ie from json) to label in above code

Comment: in your code, I saw you have following attributes which should be the UILabel for showing those info

"unRealizedProfit", "strategy" , "closedTotalUnrealizedProfit"

So in your UITableViewCell class,  just set the responded value with those labels you defined.

self.unRealizedProfit.text = [self.objCellData objectForKey:@"Profit"];

Comment: I am not sure how is your dataSource format is.  But if this self.objCellData is sth like @{@"StrategyName": @"Butterfly", @"Profit":@50},  then it should work as above.

Comment: its not working when i select that segment i hav only empty table view

Comment: Please check following by sequence.
1. If your dataSource is ready before you do [tableView reloadData], and what is your dataSource format.
2. when assign the cell.cellData = objCellData,  what is the format of your objCellData.
3. In your cell class, how do u render the labels' text based on the give cellData,  do you call [self setNeedsDisplay] or what to force the cell to redraw the content by the cellData?

Please read the samples of UITableView to try to understand the whole process first.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html